# Why would $[0,1) \times \eta$ (with lexicographic order topology) not be a manifold for $\eta > \omega_1$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

From [Wikipedia's entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29#Properties) on the long line:

> And if we tried to glue together more than $\omega_1$ copies of
>   $[0,1)$, the resulting space would no longer be locally homeomorphic
>   to $\mathbb{R}$.

Why?

Comment: I believe this is addressed in the wikipage's talk page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ALong_line_%28topology%29#Question

Answer (score 3):

Every neighbourhood of $\omega_1$ contains uncountably many ordinals, and hence

$$(\alpha,\omega_1)\times [0,1)\tag{1}$$

is not homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, since it is not second countable (there are uncountably many disjoint open subsets $\{\beta\}\times \left(\frac14,\frac34\right)$, $\alpha < \beta \leqslant \omega_1$, so the space is not second countable). Since every neighbourhood of $\{\omega_1\}\times\{0\}$ contains a set of the form $(1)$, none of its neighbourhoods is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For it to be locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, don't we just need to find a neighborhood of each point which is Euclidean? Isn't a neighborhood of a point of $\omega_1 +1 \times [0,1)$ (in lexicographic order) of the form $\beta \times (a,b)$? Or perhaps the problem comes at the point $(\omega_1, 0)$.

Comment: Shouldn't "not second countable" be replaced by "not first countable"?

Comment: @EricAuld That is a neighbourhood of $\{\omega_1\}\times \{0\}$. Every neighbourhood of that point contains a set $(\alpha,\omega_1)\times [0,1) \cup \{\omega_1\}\times [0,\varepsilon)$, I chose $\varepsilon = 1$ for simplicity.

Comment: @Daniel: No, you've got that backwards.  Not first-countable implies not second-countable. (And there are manifolds which are not second countable: topological sum of uncountably many copies of $\mathbb{R}$, for example.)

Comment: @EricAuld Yes, it is stronger. Done goofed there. Still either shows it's not homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Yes. But here every neighbourhood of $\{\omega_1\}\times\{0\}$ is not second countable, hence that has no neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. Still, gonna clarify that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Come to think of it, why does that same objection not apply to a neighborhood of $\{\omega_1\} \times \{0\}$ for the long line?

Comment: @EricAuld The long line does not contain $\{\omega_1\}\times\{0\}$ (note that $\omega_1 \times [0,1) = \bigcup \left\{\{\alpha\}\times [0,1) : \alpha < \omega_1\right\}$), it stops just before that. And thus every point of the long line has neighbourhoods containing only countably many ordinals.